# GetElementById can't get value

Tags: javascript, get, element

Do you know why this

```
function deleteInputOnClick(input){
    champ = document.getElementById(input);
    if(champ.value =='E-mail'){
        champ.value = "";
    }
}
```

works but this way

```
function deleteInputOnClick(input){
    champ = document.getElementById(input).value;
    if(champ=='E-mail'){
        champ= "";
    }
}
```

it doesn't ?

It's probably a stupid little error but I really don't see where it could be.

Thank's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not setting the value back on the element in the second way, you're just assigning it to a local variable, you still need to do `document.getElementById(input).value = champ;`

Comment: The first way is the correct way, because champ becomes a DOM object and you can manipulate the value anytime, while in the second way you can extracting the value into a variable, so you cant set it back using same variable

Answer (score 3):

That is because is `champ` is a variable that has been assigned the value of the `input` element.

Changing its value will not change the value of the input (*as it is not a two-way binding, you just assigned the value to it*)

So you need to directly target the `value` property of the `input` to alter its value

---

If you are trying to avoid using the `.value` to a lot of places you can cache both the `input` element and its `value` for different uses..

```
function deleteInputOnClick(input){
    var champ = document.getElementById(input),
        value = champ.value;
    if(value=='E-mail'){
        champ.value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById(input).value` returns a string value while `document.getElementById(input)` returns a reference (an object). So in one case only the value of the local variable is changed, in the other the original object still links to the DOM value.

Have a look at this question: [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)